# Finding and adding value to closest input field on keyup

Tags: jquery, keyup

I want to add a value to closest input field on keyup. But it is not working in dynamically added fields.

```
$(document).on('keyup', '.rate_qar' , function() {
    var qar_rate = $('#conv_rate_usd').val();
    var usd_rate = 10*qar_rate;
    $(this).parent('tr').find('input.rate_usd').val(usd_rate);
});
```

But it is not working. How can i do that? My HTML is given below. Please note that html inputs will be added dynamically.

```
<input name="rate_qar[]" type="number" min="1" placeholder="Room rate QAR" class="form-control rate_qar">
<input name="rate_usd[]" type="number" min="1" placeholder="Room type USD" class="form-control rate_usd"  >
```

Comment: Hi @Corner, plz add your HTML as well

Comment: @Victor : Done. Please check

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem could be `tr` won't be a parent of `input`, so use [.closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) instead of [.parent()](http://api.jquery.com/parent/)

```
$(this).closest('tr').find('input.rate_usd').val(usd_rate);
```